# How to work without access to subrepository in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg, mercurial-subrepos

There is a project repository A that uses framework subrepository B. Internal team has access to both. Is it possible to limit access to B for external team without breaking possibility to work with A?

Currently it says "abort: response expected (in subrepo ...)" when cancel password entering during cloning.
Or maybe there is another way for collaboration with different access rules?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually a subrepository is intended to be required by the parent repository. Perhaps you can just limit the subrepository to be read-only (not sure). Or if needed, forget the subrepository and provide the subrepository as a compiled binary that sits in a lib folder or whatever. Not sure if this fits your requirements or not, but some thoughts.

Comment: Thanks but it does not solve the problem. The subrepository is private and external team should not have any access to it. And compiled binary is not an answer because subrepository consist c++ project used in main repository project.

Comment: Ok. That's why I posted as a comment rather than an answer. One comment on the binary though, you could compile the C++ subrepository into a dll (library) and then reference the dll in the main repository.

Comment: It will be "hard to debug" solution( When I will debug project under Visual Studio - it will not give possibility to debug errors in dll.

Comment: I think if you provide the pdb file along with the dll you can debug it. It may not be perfect though (some code may have been optimized by the compiler and not match exactly what was written). It will be the code that is actually running though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not possible.  Actions on the "parent" repo require at least read access to the "child" repo.  It's probably a lot of work at this point, but one thing to consider is making them both "sibling" repositories of an "outer" umbrella repo.  That setup would look like:

```
 UMBRELLA
     PROJECT
     FRAMEWORK
```

Then people w/ access to both can checkout UMBRELLA and have both in known, predictable locations and can still do commits across both from a single location.  Those that can access PROJECT but not FRAMEWORK would check out only PROJECT.